# Do I need to waterproof the external walls of my house?

Tags: walls, exterior

I have just completed a renovation of my house. Where possible, I am putting decking around it to keep the brickwork dry and ventilated. One wall, however, will have sand and dirt added to build up the land by 30 odd centimetres. Before I so this, should I paint the lower part of the wall in bitumen paint to waterproof it or is that just overkill?

BTW: I am adding sand to protect a number of PVC pipes that run next to the wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple articles from AskTheBuilder.com.

[Exterior Foundation Wall Waterproofing](http://www.askthebuilder.com/015_Exterior_Foundation_Wall_Waterproofing.shtml)

[Foundation Waterproofing](http://www.askthebuilder.com/B339_Foundation_Waterproofing_Drain_Tile_Systems.shtml)

This is one of those things that builders and homeowners usually cheap out on, which in my opinion is a BIG mistake.  Spending the extra money now can save you tons of money later, so do the research and do it right.

I've seen [DELTA®-MS](http://www.cosella-dorken.com/bvf-ca-en/products/foundation_residential/dimplesheets/products/ms.php) used before; but I cannot vouch for it as I have never used it my self, it seems like a good product though.

Here is an article from [concretenetwork.com](http://www.concretenetwork.com/concrete/waterproofing_concrete_foundations/) that seems to be very informative, and explains different methods of waterproofing concrete.

I'm not sure how much of this information applies to your particular situation, but it should give you a good idea of some of the products and methods used for waterproofing below grade concrete/brick.

Answer (score 0):

No need to waterproof external cement rendered brick walls as water won't seep through like a sponge but just a few centimetres and they'll dry off naturally after the rain on a hot day . 
For horizontal concrete slabs such as concrete roofs and underground foundations it is a must .
For kitchen and bathroom not necessarily needed  but recommended .